# simple XML API call

Tags: php, xml, api

I am creating an application that gives users information on football matches.

I am using XML to make an API call to display data, for instance, information on multiple hotels in the area.

When the info is displayed back to the screen the first set of data is blank and no data is displayed. It's almost like it's missing the first element.

Any advice would be helpful, cheers.

[image]

```
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://xmlfeed.laterooms.com/index.aspxaid=KEYHERE&rtype=6&geolon='.$lng.'&geolat='.$lat.'')){
            trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        foreach($xml as $hotel){
          echo '<li>';
          echo '<img src ='.$hotel->images.' width ="200px" height ="200px">';
          echo '<strong><br>'.$hotel->hotel_name.'</br></strong>';
          echo '<br>Star Rating: '.$hotel->hotel_star.'';
          echo '<br>Postcode: '.$hotel->hotel_pcode.'';
          echo '<br>City: '.$hotel->hotel_city.'<br>';
          echo '<a href='.$hotel->hotel_link.'>';
          echo '<button>Book Now</button></a>';
          echo '<br><br>';

          echo'</li>';
```

Comment: Can you post your $xml output sample?

Comment: Football matches or hotels? :p .Anyway just `print_r` that $xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first element in the returned document is a `<response>` which basically tells you if the call has succeeded etc.  You should change your loop to just pick up the hotels returned...

```
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel){
```